# Img to text tensorflow

Tags: keras, tensorflow, text-generation

I read this article: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning
And i understand main concepts of this article.
We have label and image in our dataset. We pass image to our model and want to get next single word for image description and for next step give to decoder previous predicted word and cnn_encoder's output. And continue this step 'till we get  token. But i don't understand training part. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning#training I realize that my question isn't good, but i really want to find out what's going on. Please, help me. If i don't understand some concepts for that, say it to me, i'll watch some videos, read some tutorials.